# how to deal with sync and async functions in node

Tags: node.js, express

i am making a search engine and i have a database of links that i go through to get the results i need but i want when i show the results is to get the titles of those results and show them but everything is synchronous so it skips the fetching of the titles and sends the url only

here is my code:

```
app.post('/search', function(req, res){

  var resultsNum = 0;
  var results = [];
  console.log("Search Started!");

  lineReader.eachLine("searchDB.txt", function(line) {
    console.log("URL: "+line);
    getTitle(line, function(title){
      console.log("Title: "+title);
      if(similarity(req.body.searchQuery, title) > 0.9){
        resultsNum++;
        results.push(title);
      }
    });
  });
  res.send({
    "results": results
  });
});
```

Comment: Is `getTitle()` asynchronous too?  Does it have a promise interface.

Comment: What lineReader module are you using?

Comment: Please include the code for `getTitle()`.  FYI, we can't really help you when you're non-responsive to questions for clarifiation.

Comment: @jfriend00 no getTitle is synchronous

Comment: getTitle() is from the get-title-at-url module

Comment: Looking at [the code](https://github.com/m4bwav/get-title-at-url/blob/master/index.js#L35) for the module you are using, `getTitle()` is asynchronous which is why it uses a callback interface.

Comment: Still waiting to know what `lineReader` module you are using?

Comment: it's called line-reader

Comment: and i have another question i want to make the getTitle function return the title and i dont want it to return it in a callback

Comment: I've provided an answer below.  You can't make `getTitle()` return the title directly.  It's asynchronous and you can't change that, so it can only return the title in a callback, a promise or an event.  My answer below handles the fact that it's asynchronous.

Comment: so can't i just edit the function to pause node until it grabs the title?

Comment: No.  That's how asynchronous programming works in node.js.  There's a single threaded event loop.  If you pause node (like with a `while() {}` loop), then no events can get processed and then the `getTitle()` would never finish.  Instead, you have to learn how to program with asynchronous operations in node.js. 
 That's how it's architected.  If you start using promises and `async/await`, you can start writing some code that feels more like you paused a local function waiting for an asynchronous operation to finish, but node.js is still running and other events are still being processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the linereader is done processing all the lines, then you do your `res.send()`.

To make it easier to manage one line at a time and the asynchronous nature of `getTitle()`, I've switched to use the built-in readline module which lets us pause and resume the reading.  So, we can get a line, pause further reading, call the asynchronous `getTitle()` and then resume the readline instance after `getTitle()` is done.  This allows us to read and process lines one at a time even while using asynchronous processing.

The accumulated results are then sent when the linereader is all done.

```
const readline = require('readline');
const fs = require('fs');

app.post('/search', function(req, res) {
    let resultsNum = 0;
    let results = [];
    console.log("Search Started!");

    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: fs.createReadStream("searchDB.txt"), 
        crlfDelay: Infinity
    });

    // callback called for each new line
    rl.on('line', line => {
        // pause more lines until we are done with this one
        rl.pause();
        console.log("URL: " + line);
        getTitle(line, function(title, err) {
            if (err) {
                // you need to decide what to do here
                // do you skip it?  
                // do you send an error response and abort further processing
                console.log(err);
                rl.resume();
                return;
            }
            console.log("Title: " + title);
            if (similarity(req.body.searchQuery, title) > 0.9) {
                resultsNum++;
                results.push(title);
            }
            // start the readline interface so it will trigger the next line
            rl.resume();
        });

    });
    // listener for when readline is done
    rl.on('close', () => {
        res.send({
            "results": results
        });
    });
});
```

You need to decide how you want the error handling for `getTitle()` to work.  As it is coded here, it just skips any URLs that `getTitle()` returns an error for.